# Android - VideoView wont play videos with sound

Tags: android, xamarin, video, xamarin.android, android-videoview

I created a VideoPLayer in a Xamarin project using the android specific videoview. The Problem is that all the videos with play sounds on my samsung a70 (Android 9 API 28), but sometimes completely randomly the sound would not be played on my older Android 5 phone and the emulator. By randomly I mean, that the sound sometimes plays, but sometimes does not. Anyone might have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using ExoPlayer. It is developed by google and helped me with an Application i created a time ago. It is much more mature and flexible than the standard videoview-implementation. 
Here is the Github:
[ExoPlayer Github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

And I think there is also an implementation for Xamarin:

[ExoPlayer Xamarin Github](https://github.com/Baseflow/ExoPlayerXamarin)

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will have a look at it!

Comment: Okay hope it works, let me know if you have problems with ExoPlayer!